# How to programmatically restore the XLS file that was modified by a thirdparty tool

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, xls, excel-interop

We are in the process of migrating the documents from AppXTender ( a EMC Documentum tool ) to another system.

I took a XLS file from AppXtender physical store ( the tool have renamed the .XLS file to .BIN ) and I knew its an excel file I tried renaming it to .XLS but the file is not opening as excel.
I learnt that the file is been modified by the AppXtender with some content like, "FFL 1.0 followed by the original file name.XLS". 
When I open the excel in a notepad I could see this in the first line and there are couple of more lines with some text like "Embedded" and with some number.

If I manually remove those lines and save the file and still the file is not opening as excel.

What are these custom texts? how do i programmatically (C#) remove them from the excel file and restore as the proper excel file?

Thanks!
Karthik

Comment: Are you sure that it was a `.XLS` and not an `.XLSX` or `.XLSM` file?  They are the current Excle file format and much more common now, and have a very different format.

Comment: those were old files and yes it is .XLS because the custom lines FFL 1.0 followed by the file has the extension as .XLS. and also when I restore the file using their tool I can see the file saved back to .XLS.
It's the same case of .DOC files as well.

Comment: Well it seems not a trivial task. That AppXTender app may be using it's own propietary format to store the xls files, son you'd need reverse engineering to get the original file. But as a guess, i'd first try to open those .bin files in a HEX editor and look for the xls signature (D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 i think). If you find that signature,maybe there's a hope :)

Comment: Yes, I can see D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 when I open the file in a hex editor. This is appearing after the custom text that the tool has inserted. So I believe they should have inserted the text using MS office interops. But not sure what are they? Are they file headers /or custom properties?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without knowing the app and not having a look at the files, but i'd first try removing everything before the signature manually with the hex editor and see if that way Excel can open the file. If that is the case, i think it won't be difficult to code a small app that opens the files in the path you feed it, finds the excel signature, removes everything before it and saves the file..but it's just a guess

Comment: By removing the content before the excel signature using HEX editor helped. I was able to open the file in excel. However on launch this error message is being showed. 
"This workbook has lost its VBA project, ActiveX controls and any other programmability-related features".

Comment: Hmm..i don't think that's related to editing the file. Do you have visual basic for aplications installed?

Comment: No. I don't have Visual Basics.
If I have to do the removal programmatically should I open this as binary file and locate the D0 CF..and just remove everything before it? or have to use office interop to do this in cleaner way ? Not sure what can be inserted even before the xls signature.so this can not be done by an interop as its not a valid XLS file.

Comment: I would just open it as a binary file and save everything after the signature (including it of course) to another file.I think it should work just fine. No need to mess with interops :)